# Number of ways for reaching cell (a,b) in a grid of size NxM.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

An $N\times M$ grid is given, in one operation, we have to move to any diagonal adjacent cell. For example, if we are on cell $(3,3)$, in one opeartion we can move to any of $(2,4), (4,2), (2,2)$ and $(4,4)$ cells.
Starting from $(1,1)$ cell, how to find the number of ways of reaching $(a,b)$ cell after $C$ number of operations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.